# Keyboard not downloading

Tags: windows-10-mobile, keyboard, nokia-lumia-930, wordflow

I just did a hard reset, and installed Windows 10 Mobile, then I restored my Onedrive backup.

Everything was working normally, until I tried to write a message, I noticed that there are no suggestions and wordflow is not working.

When i go to *Settings -> Time & Language -> Keyboards*, all the keyboards are showing a message *Attention Required*, when I click on one it says to retry to download the *Text Suggestions*, when I do that it says *Preparing Download* for a while and then goes back to *Attention Required*.

I can't download, it and use the WordFlow keyboard.. any suggestions?

[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/windowsphone/comments/3cvxpy/any_of_you_is_having_problem_downloading_keyboard/?ref=share&ref_source=link)

Comment: Have you tried checking for updates. When you download a new language/keyboard, sometimes it's delivered as a tiny update

Comment: @Kelvinelove it only does that if you are a slow of fast insider as Simone Bonato said, that is why some people have this issue. Stable releases don't have access to this tiny updates ;)

Comment: I have had same problem for a month after resetting my phone to factory settings. Can't download Chinese traditional handwriting keyboard. Keep getting attention required after trying to download keyboard.
Tried insider updates three times, no success.
Tried download additional language speech support. Still face the same problem. However, I was able to download a simplified Chinese 12 keyboard. But, this mickey mouse keyboard is really hard to use. It is very time consuming. So, I am still searching for answers. Really regretted going to Windows 10 mobile. Wished that i have stayed with Windi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Windows mobile 10 I had the same problem (I have returned to 8.1).

In Windows Central I found [this](http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-10-mobile-insider-preview/340958-w10m-insider-bugs-defects-thread.html):

> Additional language keyboards may not be present and may not be able to install on US builds after upgrading to Windows 10.
>
> **Workaround: Reopen the Windows Insider app and re-select Insider Fast/Slow again. The download of keyboard packages will then work.**

However, I [read](http://www.windowsblogitalia.com/2016/03/disponibile-windows-10-mobile-build-14295-novita-e-guida-allinstallazione/) that with Redstone (build 14291) the bug that makes phones unable to download languages is fixed.

Comment: Done, this is why StackExchange is better than the Windows Reddit to find for solutions ;)

Comment: Does it work? :)

Comment: Yes, setting to Slow ring worked for me, I just had to click on the keyboard to download the update, then going to phone updates there was an update ready to install

Answer (score 1):

Word Flow and text suggestions aren't available with all languages. To see if your current language is supported, 
[see Windows Phone feature and service availability.](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-GB/How-to/wp8/basics/feature-and-service-availability)

Comment: If your language is in the list, go to Settings → Keyboard, tap on your language and make sure that the "Suggest text" and "Type as I flick through letters" options are enabled.

For more information on using the on-screen keyboard,[see Windows Phone typing shortcuts.][https://www.windowsphone.com/en-GB/How-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/typing-shortcuts ]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently from Gabe's blog, this issue is fixed on the Build 14295 (currently available on Slow Ring)

https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/03/25/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14295-for-pc-and-mobile/

Answer (score 1):

After searching for answers for weeks, I finally was able to do traditional Chinese handwriting again on my Lumia 640 with Windows 10 mobile.
I first went to settings, language. And add traditional Chinese language.
Then, I went to setting, speech, add Chinese simplified .
After doing this, I went back to settings, then keyboard. You can then add Chinese simplified handwriting keyboard.
After installing the simplified Chinese keyboard, you can write simplified Chinese. You can then tap the option to switch from simplified Chinese to traditional Chinese handwriting. Now, I could finally do traditional Chinese hand writings again. This is a round about way to solve this problem. But, it worked on all my three Lumia phones on Windows 10.
I still could not directly download to add the traditional chinese handwriting keyboard directly. But, it does not matter now.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Henry Chen's method of down loading Chinese Simplified Speech, actually concurrently downloaded successfully the Simplified Keyboard at the same time on my Lumia 830. (Windows 10 - insider Slow ring). Then, as suggested tap the option of switching Simplified to Traditional hand writing. Success finally!! many thanks! Why did option disappeared from my phone in the first place was a mystery!

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too, first I think my Internet filtering is reason, but what is the solution in Redstone:

1. Go to Settings > Update & security > Windows Insider program.
2. Link your account, tap <kbd>Get Started</kbd>, restart you phone.
3. After restart you can download all keyboard languages without any problem.

After installing any language pack you must restart.

Don't forget you are now an insider. If you do not want this, go to Settings > Update & security > Windows Insider program again and tap <kbd>Stop Insider Preview builds</kbd> and confirm that you want to stop getting Insider builds completely.

Comment: Is there any other way to download keyboards? My phone says if I become an insider I'll have to reset the phone to stop getting upgrades

Comment: @YaddyVirus no I think this first & last way :(

Answer (score 0):

I might be just reading too far into it....I was playing with this issue on a spare phone.  I hard reset and tested, and it worked, then I reset again to see if the keyboard stayed or got removed.  It got removed, so I tried to add it again and it failed....so I thought about it, and when it succeeded, I remembered that I had told the keyboard to 'install', then I immediately switched to the 'phone update' page to see if it was trying to download it as an update from there, which it was, and it succeeded while I was watching it from the 'phone update' settings page.  So I tried that again, and it succeeded again?  Superstition, or  weird glitch?  I have no idea :)